# Angular Dart modal window and dynamic content updates

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am using the angular.dart.ui modal component, which is working great.  I can fill it with dynamic content and have it display exactly what I want.  However, I cannot figure out how to send updates to the dynamic content in the modal window.  After the modal window displays I cannot update the content.

From looking at the source to modal.dart in the angular.dart.ui library, I'm thinking I need connect the modal window to the scope of the main window, but I don't know enough about scope in angular.dart to know how to do this.  Most of the information out there related to scope is focused on AngularJS.  It seems the pattern would be the same whether using the angular.dart.ui modal window or some other method of displaying a modal window, yes?

Pointers?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some code that shows what you try to accomplish. I think you have better chances for a response if you create an issue in the GitHub project of angular.dart.ui.

Comment: I was going to create an issue in angular.dart.ui, but figured this might be a more general question since modal windows can be created without angular.dart.ui.

That said, I created a stripped down project that illustrates what I'm trying to do, and it works fine.  

https://github.com/ReeseSys/angular-dart-ui-modal-update

The problem must be in my larger project.  I'll update with more specific questions if I can't figure out what's going on there.  Thanks for the response.